# How to start twrp recovery on android after flashing it (booting failed)?

Tags: fastboot

I'm trying to root my xiami Redmi 9T, and to do that I have to root it from twrp recovery. I've unlocked the phone(waited 7 days), got twrp from [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-3-5-a10-twrp-unnoficial-for-lime-redmi9t-beta.4233045/). What I have read online I have to boot my phone directly from fastboot because if I boot it normaly the xiaomi recovery will overwrite twrp and MIUI will force it go back to original recovery(from which you can't root the phone). But I can't boot it from fastboot because I get this unknown error I don't know how to fix. Fastboot boot twrp.img does not work as you can see.

[How error looks in cmd when I try to boot twrp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo3Pc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. First I tried to boot it up by pressing + sound button while typing "fastboot reboot" in cmd at the same time, that did not work, I would just got a black screen. Turns out the twrp was not good, so I downloaded a different one and it worked out.
The one I took was [from here](https://androidfilehost.com/?w=files&flid=320361)
called "twrp-3.5.2_10-3-lime-brigudav.img"